# Compiling Nano editor with options

Tags: compiling, nano

I am trying to compile my favorite [`nano`](https://www.nano-editor.org/) command-line text editor with some of the options.

Actually, *most of* the options in order to enable all features.

---

First, I go to Downloads directory and download the tarball:

```
cd Downloads

wget --continue https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nano-2.8.0.tar.xz
```

Then, I verify its integrity:

```
wget --continue https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nano-2.8.0.tar.xz.asc

gpg --verify nano-2.8.0.tar.xz.asc
```

It should say:

> ```
> gpg: Good signature from "Benno Schulenberg <bensberg@justemail.net>"
> ```

---

I have tried to run the configuration script as follows:

```
./configure --enable-nanorc --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-utf8 --enable-libmagic --enable-speller --disable-wrapping-as-root
```

After compilation, I end up with this; directly executed in the compiled directory:

> ```
> Compiled options: --disable-libmagic ...
> ```

I stress the:

> ```
> --disable-libmagic
> ```

As I specifically configured it with:

> ```
> --enable-libmagic
> ```

---

After no success:

1. I delete the folder to start the process over:

   ```
   rm -rf nano-2.8.0/
   ```
2. I extract again the archive:

   ```
   tar -xJf nano-2.8.0.tar.xz
   ```
3. I have tried different combinations of options, but no luck.

---

Is there anything missing in the system or am I just doing something wrong?

---

Direct execution after the compilation:

```
user@computer ~/Downloads/nano-2.8.0/src $ ./nano --version
```

> ```
> GNU nano, version 2.8.0
> (C) 1999..2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> (C) 2014..2017 the contributors to nano
> Email: nano@nano-editor.org Web: https://nano-editor.org/
> Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --disable-wrapping-as-root --enable-utf8
> ```

Comment: It's my experience that nano enables most, if not all, features, by default, when configuring. Not sure about libmagic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nano doesn't store the compiled options as provided on the `./configure` command-line, it reconstructs them based on detected features *and* the requested target ("tiny" Nano or normal Nano). For tiny Nano, it reports enabled options, since they add to the default; for normal Nano, it reports disabled options, since they remove from the default (in most cases).

In your case, you're building normal Nano, so for most options [it only reports if they're disabled](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/nano.c#n990); the exceptions are `debug`, `utf8` and `slang`. All your `--enable` options are defaults for normal Nano, so it doesn't report them in the compiled options; you'd get the same result with `./configure` and no options. You end up with `--disable-magic` because you don't have the development files for `libmagic` (see [Thomas Dickey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327791/86440)), and with `--enable-utf8` because you do have the necessary features for UTF-8 support (and it's enabled by default).

Answer (score 2):

You need a development package for libmagic.  On my Debian system that's [libmagic-dev](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libmagic-dev) for instance.

If you do not have the development library installed, the configure script tells you this.  Here is what it shows without the library:

```
checking whether LINES and COLS can be redefined... yes
checking magic.h usability... no
checking magic.h presence... no
checking for magic.h... no
checking for magic_open in -lmagic... no
```

and after installing the package:

```
checking whether LINES and COLS can be redefined... yes
checking magic.h usability... yes
checking magic.h presence... yes
checking for magic.h... yes
checking for magic_open in -lmagic... yes
```

The feature that you are checking is a definition in `config.h`, i.e., `HAVE_LIBMAGIC` (though you also need the header file, as shown):

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the `magic' library (-lmagic). */
#define HAVE_LIBMAGIC 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the `z' library (-lz). */
#define HAVE_LIBZ 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <limits.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_LIMITS_H 1

/* Define to 1 if you have the <magic.h> header file. */
#define HAVE_MAGIC_H 1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?49761)'s reply:

> All options are enabled by default (except debug), so all your --enable-nanorc etcetera are superfluous. And as Thomas has explained on Stackexhange, you need some -dev package if you want libmagic support (but I would advice against it -- it brings very little and is a major slowdown during startup).

Both of you are right. Thank you [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327791/126755) and [Stephen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327834/126755).

Only one thing was still missing; `nano` does not read my `/etc/nanorc` file as [reported](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47437).

According to the developer, the following may do, *and it does*:

```
sudo ln -nsf /etc/nanorc /usr/local/etc/
```