# Nano - jump to end of file

Tags: nano

I have some long log files. I can view the last lines with `tail -n 50 file.txt`, but sometimes I need to edit those last lines.

How do I jump straight to the end of a file when viewing it with `nano`?

Comment: Try out `vim` :-P

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson That does not work! You are using a user defined command! But now try out `vim` in a portable way **G**

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I can't tell whether you're being sarcastic, but it's not a user-defined command. It's an emoticon. We used to use these things before someone let Unicode smoke weed.

Comment: Sarcastic, of course!  I tried your command: `:` to open command line, than `-`, `P` and enter. That's what I got: "E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command". All the best!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Open the file with `nano file.txt`.

Now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: You can also do Ctrl+W, Ctrl+V - depending on what is more comfortable for your hands :)

Comment: @psmears that depends on the version. v2.4 has your shortcuts. The current version v4.0 has the shortcuts Marko mentions. Very annoying.

Comment: @Mausy5043: Versions up to at least 2.4 have both sets of shortcuts. Version 4.0 seems to have removed Ctrl+W, Ctrl+V, which is annoying; it does have Ctrl+W, Ctrl+T, Ctrl+Y which is at least just on the letter keys, but is longer :-(

Comment: Those shortcuts do not work very well in Windows / Putty

Comment: I am using nano editor with Italian keyboard. Maybe this is the reason, however in my environment the shortcut is Ctrl + -

Comment: On ubuntu gnome terminal this just decreases the text size....

Answer (score 36):

Many editors support the `+NNN` option on the command line to jump directly to line *NNN*. Luckily for you, `nano` appears to jump to the end if the line number given is past the end of file, so you could use something like:

```
nano +999999 file
```

That also works in `joe`, but not in, e.g. `less` or VIM, they complain about going past EOF. (at least the ones on my system. `less +G file` and `vi +$ file` work in those.)

Of course something like `$EDITOR +$(wc -l file) file` would probably work in most editors, but that's a bit silly and involves reading the file twice.

Comment: Or with nano already open, use <kbd>Alt/<kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> then enter 99999

Comment: `nano +-1 file` is a superior version of this answer, thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/476361/lesha-lyushen (scroll to bottom of page) - his answer deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 29):

From the built-in Nano help (`^G`):

```
M-\   (^Home)   Go to the first line of the file
M-/   (^End)    Go to the last line of the file
```

So, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to go to the *first line* or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to go to the *last line*.

- This would be the equivalent of <kbd>gg</kbd> (start) or <kbd>G</kbd> (end) in *vim*.
- This also states that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> should work, but <del>that's never worked for me</del> they seem to work natively on console/desktop but not via SSH using PuTTY.
- The way I remember this is that `/` is near the bottom of the keyboard and `\` is near the top.

If you want a *command*, you could write a function in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` to use the line count from `wc`:

```sh
function nano-end {
    # if the file exists, jump to the end
    # otherwise, just open an empty nano
    [ -f "$1" ] && nano +$(wc -l "$1") || nano
}
```

Now just type `nano-end filename` to open the file to its last line!

Comment: "The way I remember this is that / is near the bottom of the keyboard and \ is near the top" >> This is very good

Comment: As of now, `ctrl+w` `ctrl+v` conflicts with WSL 2's default keybindings. `alt+/` works without a hitch.

Answer (score 8):

In order to go directly to the end of the file in nano, just type:
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. Also, if you wanna jump to a first line: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: On some systems Alt (or Meta) is toggled by the Esc key :-\

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> is working, if you have a recent (compiled) version of [`nano`](https://www.nano-editor.org/download.php) editor.

If you don't know, how to do it, you may read [Compiling Nano editor with options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327765/126755)

Note, that in newer systems, e.g. based on Ubuntu 18.04, there already is such a version.

From the [changelog](https://www.nano-editor.org/news.php):

### 2017 April 12 - GNU nano 2.8.1

... makes ^Home and ^End
go to the start and end of the file (on terminals that
support those keystrokes) ...

### PuTTY vs Cygwin

I do not have PuTTY installed, here we have to rely on other claims these key combinations don't work in Windows 10 + PuTTY + SSH + nano > 2.8.1.

On the other hand, I have Cygwin, and Windows 10 + Cygwin + SSH + nano > 2.8.1 works Ok.

Answer (score 2):

OP wants me to add an answer for jumping to the last line in `vim`.

<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will get you to the beginning of the last line.

<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> will get you to the end of last line and insert mode will be activated.

Comment: If you want to do this in insert mode, do `C-o G`. Not that you would want to do that if you were using vim right...

Answer (score 2):

No need to use +999999, use instead -1, it works perfectly

```
nano +-1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has trouble with this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>, enter a large number (such as 9999999) then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This command will go to line 9999999; if the file has fewer than 9999999 line then it will go to the last line.